# Can something have multiple functions according to Aristotle?

Tags: aristotle

I was reading Aristotle’s function argument and I’m having trouble figuring out if things could have multiple functions. It seems like he implies that things cannot have multiple functions but this is not said explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean multiple ends?

Comment: Aren’t an end and a function different? I’m specifically referring to when he looks for example for the function of a bodily part. Could they not have multiple?

Comment: An artifact can have more than one.

Comment: Please give the reference to the passage in Aristotle's work, which you are reading; thanks.

Comment: the passage is in the nicomachean ethics I 7.1097b22-a20

Comment: No, they aren't the same. Just that Aristotle is a lot more famous for his comments on ends than on function, so I thought you might be using the wrong word. Never mind :)

Comment: Can explain how they are different? Because the more that I think about it it seems to me that end (telos) and function are the same and can be used interchangeably in his function argument.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Aristotle's discussion of function, but from what you describe, a function can be an end, but not all ends are functions, since a function always has a purpose outside itself, but an end can be its own purpose.

Comment: here is a good discussion on functions "https://iep.utm.edu/func-exp/". the topic is quite complicated with differing viewpoints. Personally I think a function is an ability ascribed to some thing by humans that seems important, in one view the function of the heart is to pump blood but on another view the function of the hart could be held to be noise-making.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a thing have more than one final cause?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/can-a-thing-have-more-than-one-final-cause)